# C# Ext.net: Show window with Visible="false"

Tags: c#, extjs, ext.net

How I can show a window when it has `Visible="false"`?

```
<ext:Window ID="WndwLinkDoc" runat="server"
                        Width="650" Height="350" CloseAction="Hide"                      
                        X="120" Y="120" Visible="false" Title="Link doc"
                        ConstrainHeader="true"
                        Layout="FitLayout">
```

I tried with
`WndwLinkDoc.Show()`
but its not working.

If I use `Hidden="true"` I have problem accessing this:

```
<ext:Hidden runat="server" ID="hdnclid" />
```

In store in the window by passing its value to Parameter:

```
<ExtraParams>
     <ext:Parameter Name="clientid" Value="#{hdnclid}.value" Mode="Raw"/> //error hdnclid undefined
</ExtraParams>
```

Full window code:

```
<ext:Hidden runat="server" ID="hdnclid" />
<ext:Window ID="WndwLinkDoc" runat="server"
                        Width="650" Height="350" CloseAction="Hide"                      
                        X="120" Y="120" Visible="false" Title="Link doc"
                        ConstrainHeader="true"
                        Layout="FitLayout">                                                
                        <Items>
                            <ext:ComboBox ID="CmbFindDoc" runat="server"
                                        DisplayField="FullName"
                                        ValueField="id"
                                        TypeAhead="true"
                                        FieldLabel="Doctor"
                                        Width="470" MaxLength="150"
                                        PageSize="10" AllowBlank="false"
                                        LabelWidth="130" ForceSelection="true" 
                                        HideTrigger="false"
                                        MinChars="0"
                                        TriggerAction="Query">
                                        <ListConfig ID="lstc" LoadingText="Searching...">
                                                <ItemTpl runat="server">
                                                    <Html>
                                                        <div class="search-item">
                                                            <h3>{DocTitle} {FullName}</h3>
                                                            {Speciality1}, {Address} - {City} &nbsp {Phone} {Mobile} {Email}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </html>
                                                </ItemTpl>
                                            </ListConfig>
                                            <Store>
                                                <ext:Store ID="storeDocSearch" runat="server" AutoLoad="false">
                                                    <Proxy>
                                                        <ext:AjaxProxy Url="/SearchControls/DoctorSearch.ashx">
                                                            <ActionMethods Read="POST" />
                                                            <Reader>
                                                                <ext:JsonReader RootProperty="Doc" TotalProperty="total"  />
                                                            </Reader>
                                                            <ExtraParams>
                                                                <ext:Parameter Name="clientid" Value="#{hdnclid}.value" Mode="Raw"/>
                                                            </ExtraParams>
                                                        </ext:AjaxProxy>
                                                    </Proxy>
                                                    <Model>
                                                        <ext:Model ID="mdl" runat="server">
                                                            <Fields>
                                                                <ext:ModelField Name="id" Type="Int" />
                                                                <ext:ModelField Name="FullName" />
                                                            </Fields>
                                                        </ext:Model>
                                                    </Model>
                                                </ext:Store>
                                            </Store>
                                        </ext:ComboBox>
                            <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Link doc" >
                            </ext:Button>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Window>
```

Comment: Visibile="true"

Comment: no its not working

Comment: if you set `visible=false`, the window will not be rendered on the client side and therefore you cannot reference it in client-side JavaScript code.  If you change that to `hidden=true`, the window will be accessible on the client and you can show it using `App.WndwLinkDoc.show()`.  What is the purpose of the hiddenfield `hdnclid`?

Comment: did you try WndwLinkDoc.setVisible(true);?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ext:Window ID="WndwLinkDoc" runat="server"
                        Width="650" Height="350" CloseAction="Hide"                      
                        X="120" Y="120" **Hidden="true"** Title="Link doc"
                        ConstrainHeader="true"
                        Layout="FitLayout">
```

And you can use from code-behind ;

```
WndwLinkDoc.Hide();
WndwLinkDoc.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that you want to show this window during DirectEvent in Code Behind, right? In that case, you have to use Render method before setting Visible flag to true. Here is a working example:

*.aspx

```
<ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
<ext:Window runat="server" ID="myWindow" Visible="false" Title="Window Test"  />
<ext:Button runat="server" Text="Show Window">
    <DirectEvents>
        <Click OnEvent="Button_Click" />
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

*.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    if (!myWindow.Visible)
    {
        myWindow.Visible = true;
        myWindow.Render();
    }
}
```